# error c2039 ' ctor ' is not a member of 'cv::flann::Index_<T>'

Tags: c++, opencv

I use Visual Studio 2013 and OpenCV 2.3.1. I tried to execute this code:

```cpp
#include<opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv\cv.h>
#include<opencv\highgui.h>
#include<iostream>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
int main()
{
    cv::Mat im_rgb = cv::imread("1.jpg", 1);
    cv::Mat im_gray;
    cv::cvtColor(im_rgb, im_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    cv::namedWindow("image RGB", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cv::namedWindow("image GRAY", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cv::imshow("image RGB", im_rgb);
    cv::imshow("image gray", im_gray);
    cvWaitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

and I have this error :

```cpp
error c2039 ' ctor ' is not a member of  'cv::flann::Index_<T>'
```

Comment: Which line of code is being referenced?

Comment: where did you use `flann`?

Comment: I don't use it , this is all my only code